# Need help, array

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, arraylist

in the following code fragment

```
for (int i=1; i<50; i++){
    arr[i-1] = i+1;

}
```

what would be the final value of the cell with index 3 of the array arr???

2, 5, 3, 0 or 4?

I need it, please, help me c:

Comment: How is 'arr' defined? Have you tried running it to check the output yourself?

Comment: is a code fragment, I guess the rest would be correct, the only thing I need to know is its final value.
2, 5 ,3 ,0 or 4

Comment: What's your guess? How would you evaluate it? What's the value of `i`, when it writes to `arr[3]`? What's the value of `i+1` in this case?

Answer (score 1):

Let's have a look:

```
i   array index   value
        (i-1)      (i+1)
1         0         2 
2         1         3 
3         2         4 
4         3         5 
5         4         6 
6         5         7
. . .
```

Since indices start with 0, index 3 has the value 5

(Assuming `int arr[50];`)

Comment: Please be careful with answering questions which compiling and running can answer. They tend to be "please help my in the exam I am taking right now" questions. And, as you now can see, tend to be identified as off-topic. Whether or not you feel good with helping others in cheating themselves (and those who offer the exam and whatever is the reward for it) is up to you. But I want to make sure that you understand the possible background with this kind of question.